# Loading up one spring beans file of another based on a variable?

Tags: java, spring

I am working with Spring, and I have an xml file full of beans.

Now, some of these beans I want to bring into my application if one variable is true, and another one if it is false.

Does anybody know how I might achieve this?

EDIT : By "Bring into my application" - I mean I want to instantiate them based on some criteria.

Comment: Edit to reflect an answer... Essentially, I only want to instantiate the beans if a certain criteria is met. Such as Environment="Dev", or Environment="Prod".

Comment: Generally we use 2 different configuration files and different profiles. I have never met this problem and I think it's a design problem. You shouldn't get this problem.

Comment: I agree with you completely, but my bosses wont take no for an answer here - and I literally have to get this to work. Splitting them into two different files is totally an option - do you know of any resources for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use profiles, and declare beans inside a profile. One of this beans can be your property placeholder.

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:properties/application-default.properties, classpath:properties/application-dev.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
</beans>

<beans profile="test">
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:properties/application-default.properties, classpath:properties/application-test.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
</beans>
```

Then you can generate with maven

```
mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

You can see more here

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/load-environment-configurations-and-properties-with-spring-example/

https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: is it possible to make this work with a different parameter than profiles.active?

Comment: You can programmatically set active profiles by calling SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles(…​) before your application runs. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Awesome - and I have one final question here - and then I can def mark this as best answer - what if I need some of my beans to load on all profiles? Can I just choose not to set a profile on those beans, and they will load in every profile?

Comment: Marking as best answer because it is correct - However, I just realized it wont be of use to me right now because I am using Spring 3.0 for this project at work. Profiles were added in 3.1.